# NETSUITE: Saved Search for Unapplied Payments - Need Main line filter for unapplied balance

Tags: netsuite

I've created a Saved Search to show Unapplied Payments with an Amount Remaining above 0. This correctly displays everything I need however I want to use the inline editing and I'm getting the warning "Only searches filtered to the main line support editing" because of the "Amount Remaining is above 0". Is there any main line header field I can use to still achieve this? I was trying to find a mainline status but I'm not finding anything other than Deposited which doesn't help--I need unapplied/balance remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following standard criteria filter should work: Filter = Main Line, and Description = is true.